# Fix Error: The component for route 'Home' must be a React component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to used react-navigation but I can not get it to work when I move each screens' components into multiple files.  I always get this error: "The component for route 'Home' must be a React component". This error doesn't happen if I move all of the code into one file, so I'm not sure what the difference is.

Here is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

import { HomeScreen } from './screens/HomeScreen';
import { JoinScreen  from './screens/JoinScreen';
import { HostScreen } from './screens/HostScreen';


const Root = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    Details: {
      screen: JoinScreen,
    }
  }, 
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Root />
    )
  }
}
```

And here is my .screens/HomeScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Hello World</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think that if you change this line:

```
import { HomeScreen } from './screens/HomeScreen';
```

to:

```
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
```

(i.e. removing the braces around `HomeScreen`) then it will work. Because you used `export default` in the `HomeScreen` component's source file, you don't need the [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on the `import`. This is attempting to access a variable called `HomeScreen` on the component, which is resolving to `undefined` and causes the error you saw.

Alternatively, you can remove the `default` from `export default` and keep the `import` the same. I personally prefer removing the braces as the code looks cleaner.

There's also a missing closing brace on this line:

```
import { JoinScreen  from './screens/JoinScreen';
```

But I assumed that was a typo ;)

Comment: For me, only the 'default' word from HomeScreen file fixed it. I had to keep the braces intact in the App.js when importing Home and other screens.

Answer (score 5):

I think that react is having a problem figuring out what to import
Since you're exporting one thing by default 
You should replace

```
import { HomeScreen } from './screens/HomeScreen';
```

with

```
import  HomeScreen  from './screens/HomeScreen';
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
Home: {
   screen: () => <HomeScreen/>,
},
```

Answer (score 1):

It also happens if you do not export your class.

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your js file at the bottom add this Line

```
export default MainActivity;


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

class MainActivity extends Component{
  ...
}
export default MainActivity;
```

Comment: Hi , can you please elaborate a bit on your answer to make it more meaningful and clear.

Comment: You save my day. I feel so dumb for this silly mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've mentioned the default, I think that if you change this line:

```
import { HomeScreen } from './screens/HomeScreen';
```

to:

```
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
```

This would solve the issue.  Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

Keep the braces intact for your external screen files imports. Just do the following and it should run on both Android and iOS simulators regardless

```
// HomeScreen.js
... all imports
export class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
...
```

This fixed the issue for me in both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I was using **"react"** instead of **'react'**. I removed the double quotes from react and the error gone away.