# The component for route 'x' must be a React Component

Tags: react-native, react-native-tabnavigator

this seems to be a common problem with react navigation once they updated their API

looked at [Fix Error: The component for route 'Home' must be a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267531/fix-error-the-component-for-route-home-must-be-a-react-component)

neither `profile` nor `camera` components want to load into this tabNavigator. Any suggestions?

**Camera.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Camera extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Text>Camera</Text>
        );
    }
}

export default Camera;
```

**InstaClone.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native' 
import Camera from './components/screens'
import {MainFeed, Login, Profile} from './components/screens'
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'

const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    feed: MainFeed,
    Camera: Camera,
    profile: Profile
});

const MainStack = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
    login: Login,
    main: Tabs
}));

const MainStack = createAppContainer(Tabs);

class InstaClone extends Component {
    render() {
        return <MainStack/>
    }
}


export default InstaClone;
```

Comment: I'm having a similar error. Did you solve this?

Comment: asus, did you resolve this yet?